# activebackground option on tkinter button not taken into account on windows 10

Tags: python, linux, windows, button, tkinter

I am using tkinter buttons and added the `activebackground` argument to them which make the background of the button becoming colored with the color you want when the button is being hovered.

```py
new_championship_button = Button(
    host_window,
    bg='black',
    image=resized_photo,
    activebackground="white",
    bd=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: create_new_championship()
)
```

This code produces the expected result when run on Ubuntu but doesn't when run on windows 10.

Does anyone know how to fix that?

Thank you for your help :)